# How do I modify an XML file's elements and then print the whole thing

Tags: java, xml, rss

I have been tasked with modifying a String which contains an RSS feed. It has  elements in it. I need to modify these link elements and then output the whole things. I've tried using  Documentbuilder but every time I try to modify a node it deletes all descendant nodes.

Can anyone suggest an easy way to retrieve and modify these nodes and then print the entire feed.

```
public Document XMLParser(String rssFeed){
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = null;
    String nodeContents = null;
    String newXML = "";
    try {
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(rssFeed.getBytes("utf-8"))));

        Node node = doc.getFirstChild();
        NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node curNode = nodeList.item(i);
            if ("link".equals(curNode.getNodeName()) || "channel".equals(curNode.getNodeName())) {
                nodeContents = curNode.getTextContent();
                nodeContents = "new contents";
                curNode.setTextContent(nodeContents);
            }
        }
        return doc;

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

RSS sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
    <title>title for the channel</title>
    <link><![CDATA[www.whatever.com]]></link>
    <description><![CDATA[description of the channel.]]></description>
    <item>
        <title><![CDATA[title of the link]]></title>
        <description><![CDATA[description of the link]]></description>
        <link><![CDATA[www.whatever.com]]></link>
        <enclosure url="thepictureURL" length="21830" type="image/png" />
        <pubDate>Thu, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 EDT</pubDate>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Show us your code (the one that deletes the descendant nodes)

Comment: Ok, I added the code in question.

Comment: Also include a sample of your RSS data.

Comment: ok, rss added in the real one there is more than one item section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out for `setTextContent(text)`. If you call it on a node that has child nodes, those will get replaced with the `text`.

If the RSS is not too big you can load it into memory - parse it into DOM. Modify the contents of the `<link>` nodes. Then serialize the DOM back to string:

```
public static String processLinks(String rssFeed) throws Exception {
  DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder builder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(rssFeed)));

  NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("link");
  for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node link = nodeList.item(i);
    String value = link.getTextContent();
    //Do the processing. For example:
    if(!value.startsWith("http://")) {
      link.setTextContent("http://"+value);
    }
  }
  return toString(doc);
}

private static String toString(Document doc) throws Exception {
  TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
  return writer.toString();
}
```

Comment: sweet! Thanks, I"ll see if I can give it a try before I head home tonight.

Comment: This seems to have been the issue. thanks for the help1